# Login Process with jQuery Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

Hey guys I need some help.

My problem is the error `div` is not displaying the content that I want it to appear in the success function of my AJAX request. I tried alerting the response and it returns true if user-name and password is correct and returns false if incorrect.

I don't know why its not working.

so this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

  <div class="container" name="main-div">
    <div id="error">
AA
    </div>
    <center>
      <div name="login-div">
      <h2>LOGIN PAGE</h2>
      <form method="post" class="login_form">
          Username: <input type="text" name="username"></br></br>
          Password: <input type="password" name="password"></br></br>
          <button type="submit"  name="button_login" id="button_login">LOGIN</button>
      </form>
      </div>
      </center>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button_login").click(function(){
      var data = $(".login_form").serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login_process.php',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(){
          alert(data);
        },
        success : function(response){
          //alert(response);
          if(response=="true"){
            $("#error").html("CORRECT USERNAME AND PASSWORD")
            //window.location="home.php";
        }else{
            $("#error").html('<a>WRONG</a>');
          });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it return the string `"true"` or a boolean `true`? because a boolean is more likely so you'd need to remove the quote marks from around the "true" and preferably use three equal signs for a strict check of it, it's good practice. to test just `console.log(typeof response)`

Comment: @MarkWalters its a string.. I tried adding an alert inside the if statement to check if it meets the condition and it did

Comment: Does the element with id `error` exist on the page? Have you tried to inspect the page and see if the content gets set? What HTML node is `#error`?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra closing bracket in the script what you wrote. Try to open the page in the chrome and open the developers console to see the syntax error.

```
Login.html:44 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

I corrected the syntax as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button_login").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(".login_form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'login_process.php',
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function(){
      alert(data);
    },
    success : function(response){
      //alert(response);
        if(response=="true"){
            $("#error").html("CORRECT USERNAME AND PASSWORD")
        //window.location="home.php";
        }else{
            $("#error").html('<a>WRONG</a>');
        }
    },
    error : function(response) {
        $("#error").html('error'+ error);
    }

  });
});
```

});

Comment: i removed the extra closing bracket... but its still not loading.

I observed that the whole page refreshes after the whole ajax request which restores the previous value of the error div which is "AA"

Comment: I had updated the code see the ajax call is successful, check is it going to success  or error block.